# Develop and Deploy Angular 4 to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, angular-cli

I'm looking for a complete solution to develop an Angular 4 app in Visual Studio and then Deploy (publish) it to Azure.

I would like to use built-in Visual Studio's templates to generate the app and use the it's publish window to deploy it to Azure.

Any suggestion?

ps: I'm using the latest VS2017

Comment: The built-in Angular template does not use the Angular CLI. There is an Angular CLI template at Visual Studio Marketplace. They both support publishing from Visual Studio to Azure.

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

while investigating for similar question I came accros this:
https://johnpapa.net/deploy-angular-to-azure-vsts-angular-cli/

Comment: Thanks @fred-klein, that one is perfect walkthrough if you want to do a continues deploy but what I was looking for to be able to deploy to Azure from local pc.